# Make a timer perform bidder00_TextChanged Event

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, textchanged

I am trying to figure out how to make it that when my `timer` ticks, it performs a `bidder00_TextChanged`, or something like that.

Is this even possible to do? and if it isn't, is there any other way to do it?
I tried to search Google for it but i didn't get any results, if you find anything that i missed please post it here.

I don't really have any code but here it is:

```
private void bidder00_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bidder00.Text == addbidder1.Text)
    {
        bidBtn1.PerformClick();
    }
}
```

That is my `TextChanged` Event

My `timer` doesn't have any code because it is going to perform the `bidder00_TextChanged` Event.

Comment: Show us some code so we can understand better whar are you trying to achieve here.

Comment: Instead of firing the event, why don't you call the same method both from the TextChanged Event and the Timer Tick Event?

Comment: Umm. What *exactly* do you want?

Comment: I want my timer to perform my bidder00_TextChanged Event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a method `Perform()` and call it from within your event handlers :

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Perform();
}

private void bidder00_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Perform();
}

private void Perform()
{
   if (bidder00.Text == addbidder1.Text)
   {
      bidBtn1.PerformClick();
   }
}
```

Comment: I think that is what i needed! I'll try that and tell you if that worked.

Comment: @Dozer789  Also I think you should extract bidBtn event handler to separate method, and call it instead of performing click

Comment: @Dozer789 like my answer suggests

Comment: @James I am using the code that AbZy said, how do i Call insted of PerformClick

Comment: As I said in my answer, you need to remove the coupling between your business logic & your click event. UI controls should be used to delegate calls to your actual model they shouldn't have *any* logic behind them, unless it's UI specific. I will update my answer to give you an example

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have coupled your actual logic with your `click` event which is not a good idea. Separate the code out into a separate function and have both parts of the application call the same code e.g.

```
private void SubmitBid()
{
    // code you want to execute
}

private void OnSubmitBid()
{
     // confirm whether we can actually submit the bid
     if (bidder00.Text == addbidder1.Text)
     {
          SubmitBid();
     }
}

private void Timer1_OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // trigger code from timer
    OnSubmitBid();
}

private void bidder00_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // trigger code from text change
    OnSubmitBid();
}

private void btnBid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // trigger code from button press
    OnSubmitBid();
}
```

Notice all the UI controls trigger the same code. There is an extra call in there for the text control validation (i.e. `OnSubmitBid()`) - if this wasn't required then you would just call `SubmitBid` directly.

Comment: Just did. Thanks a lot for all of your help!